# How to read .csv and .csv.gz file with all executors in EMR cluster

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr, spark-structured-streaming

I am using aws emr service (emr 6.9.0) with one core node and 8 executors of instance type m5.2xlarge. My requirement is to execute read csv or csv.gz file through a spark scala job and write it into parquet with few changes in data.

**Issue which I have encountered is** when reading data from csv or csv.gz file it only use one executor to read and then to write data to parquet it uses all executors. Simply my requirement is to read those csv or csv.gz files from all executors as these files are very large and take more time to complete the job.

Can you guys give me any specific reason to this and a way to overcome this issue ?

Comment: Is it a read from S3 ?

Comment: @mgosk Yes it is read from S3

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are reading from S3, By default, Spark reads a CSV file as a single partition. This means that only one executor is used to read the data. To improve parallelism during the reading phase, you can increase the number of partitions when reading the data using the repartition method. For exampleval

```
csvData = spark.read.csv("s3://your-bucket/path/to/data.csv").repartition(8) // or the number of executors you have
```

Comment: Is this method work for csv.gz files also

Comment: This isn't quite accurate - CSV files are splittable so multiple executors can read the data. Spark will split the CSV file into 128mib partitions. However, gzip'ed CSV files are *not* splittable so in that case only one executor can read the file.